# How can I create Quilt data packages with R instead of Python?

Tags: python, r, quiltdata

Quilt has a [Python library](https://pypi.org/project/quilt3/) (`quilt3`) but I use [R](https://www.r-project.org/) for all my scientific workflows. Is there an R interface that I can use to take advantage of Quilt's data version control and data lineage functionality for my datasets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Disclaimer: I originally wrote this answer when I was working at Quilt Data]*

As of writing there is not an R package for `quilt3`.

However, you can use the `quilt3` [command line interface](https://docs.quiltdata.com/api-reference/cli) (CLI), which provides all the functionality of the Python library (such as [decorating your data packages with metadata](https://docs.quiltdata.com/catalog/metadata), validating your package data & metadata against [Quilt Workflows](https://docs.quiltdata.com/advanced/workflows), running the catalog locally, etc). There are currently two ways of incorporating the `quilt3` CLI in your scientific workflows:

1. Output data from your R workflows to the file system and then call `quilt3` directly. For example as part of a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) (like [Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/)), other orchestration software (such as [Prefect](https://www.prefect.io/)), or even as basic as a shell script.
2. Call the `system` ([link](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html)) or `system2` ([link](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system2.html)) R-commands which can invoke operating system (OS) commands like `quilt3` directly inside of your R script.

Additionally, you can use the `reticulate` [package](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/) for R.